# i am not understanding this statement in Test Driven Development "Test code requires maintenance as well as production code"

Tags: tdd

what is the meaning of this below statement, by [Joosep Simm](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/if-and-when-you-should-use-test-driven-development/)

> Test code requires maintenance as well as production code....
>   test code grows linearly with production code. All lines of code require maintenance, which means cost. The cost is easiest to acknowledge when a change to existing functionality is made. The tests have to be modified as well as production code. This becomes a problem when multiple tests execute the same line of production code. This usually happens when there are too many high-level tests. The highest level test is an end-to-end test, which starts by invoking the GUI and goes all the way down to the data storage level. But it’s not only the highest-level test that can cause problems.

Comment: Without any formating, it is not clear what parts of your question are the “statement” you say you are confused by, and your own commentary.

Comment: Please edit your question to format it properly. What is that your do not understand? The part of sentence reported in the title?

Comment: And please clarify if the provided answer goes in the right direction and is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Test code requires maintenance as well as production code

People *might* assume that they *never* have to read/adapt/**improve** test code after it has been written, except when the corresponding production code changes or the underlying feature needs to be enhanced.

That quote tries to give reasons to explain what that assumption "We don't have to improve our test code (independently of the production code)!" is wrong.

The point is: there are very specific requirements for test code. It should help you:

- to really test your production code **and**
- to quickly identify bugs

In other words: it is essential that your test code is *also* easy to read and maintain over time.

This means that *after* you are done developing and testing a feature, it can be worthwhile to improve your test code. To ensure that it didn't turn into hard to read spaghetti/legacy code that will give headaches in the future!

Comment: I would argue that test will help _to quickly identify bugs_, because if this is a logic bug (not a spelling, missing value mistake), then the test will be written following "bug" logic.